# Casting and Concatenation in One line

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have seen this done in code once or twice but can't find an example now.  Until recently I was working in webforms and have switched to MVC. I have looked around and not found a whole lot on this.  The code below is from my controller to pull in the values and display in my view model.  I need to take the m.body.MembersId from MSMQ. I know what the problem is I just dont know how to use Linq like this.

The Situation , I need to do all this in one line. Cast the memberIds information that was originally a list named MembersId back to a list to display it but also do a string.join so that the entire list is displayed as one string.  While I am aware of how to do both of those by themselves but to do in one line is proving beyond me.  I will openly admit I am fairly new to linq and am learning as I go.
This is the class

```
public class MsgChildClass{
    public string SourceSystem { get; set; }
    public List<string> MemberIds { get; set; }
    public string ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Error { get; set; }
}
```

this is the function

```
    public ActionResult GetAllMessages() {

        string queueName = (ViewBag.QueueName != null) ? ViewBag.QueueName : Request.QueryString["queueName"];
        Session["CurrentQueueName"] = queueName;
        TempData["queueName"] = queueName;
        ViewBag.QueueName = queueName;

        var queue = _Queues[queueName];

        queue.MessageReadPropertyFilter.ArrivedTime = true;
        queue.MessageReadPropertyFilter.Body = true;
        queue.Formatter = new JsonMessageFormatter();

        var messages = queue.GetMessages();

        var model = messages.Select(m =>
                    new ViewModel() {
                        Id = m.Id,
                        Date = m.ArrivedTime,
                        SourceSystem = ((MsgChildClass)m.Body).SourceSystem,
                        DeletedMemberIds =  ((MsgChildClass)m.Body).DeletedMemberIds,//OrderByDescend(x => x);                string.Join(",",((MsgChildClass)m.Body).DeletedMemberIds),
                        ParentMemberId = ((MsgChildClass)m.Body).ParentId,
                        Error = ((MsgChildClass)m.Body).Error,
                        QueName = queueName
                    }).ToList();
        return Json(model.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

View Model

```
public class ViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    //[Required]
    [Display(Name = "Arrival Time")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Source System")]
    public string SourceSystem { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Member Ids")]
    public List <string> MemberIds { get; set; }


    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Parent Member Id")]
    public string ParentMemberId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Error")]
    public string Error { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "QueName")]
    public string QueName { get; set; }



}
```

This is what I have. All of it works correctly except the memberids. Debugging shows me that the memberids have the value but I am not drilling down far enough.  So hopefully some one can help me out quite a bit as been quite few hours at this point.  Google is great but he didnt help me out with this one.

Comment: Are you sure it's not just a typo? You're missing a `,` after `((MsgChildClass)m.Body).MemberIds`.

Comment: @Joel Of what type is `((MsgChildClass)m.Body).MemberIds` ? What is wrong with your current code?

Comment: @AlexanderDerck that was just a typo from the copy and paste sorry about that

Comment: @Joel But what exactly is wrong? Are you getting a runtime exception, compiler error?

Comment: I get no compiler error or runtime error.  the code is a select for a datatable.js for each item in an array.The problem is that the list string does not display everything else.  I to take the list string and join it so that it will be one single string for display

Comment: in debug MemberIds show a Value of Count = 3 when it needs to be showing "test1, test2, test3" for my example

Comment: @har07 that is a list<string>

Comment: @GertArnold understood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code was correct which was the maddening part.  debugger was telling me the values were there.  But the part I didnt look at was how the datatable.js was loading the data for display.  After seeing that was done incorrect, I corrected it and now the list is now displayed as string , string, string which is what I was needing so thanks every one

Answer (score 0):

It's cleaner and more efficient if you only cast once into a variable. And another advantage is that you can add a break point and look at `msgChild`.

```
var model = messages.Select(m =>
{
    var msgChild = (MsgChildClass)m.Body;

    return new ViewModel
    {
        Id = m.Id,
        Date = m.ArrivedTime,
        SourceSystem = msgChild.SourceSystem,
        MemberIds = msgChild.MemberIds,
        ParentMemberId = msgChild.ParentId,
        Error = msgChild.Error,
        QueName = queueName
    };
}).ToList();
```

Comment: I have edited and shown more code. To explain the situation a little better then I have